# How to call webservice from TSQL? (SQL SERVER 2000)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I want to call a webservice from TSQL in SQL Server 2000. I tried with the following code:

```sql
Declare @Object as Int; 
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get','http://server/ws/service1.asmx/Test', 'false';
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send';
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT;
Select @ResponseText Resultado;
Exec sp_OADestroy @Object;
```

For this to work I had to enable Ole Automation:

```sql
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

In my test server works fine, the problem is that on the production server to run

```sql
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
```

I get the following error:

> The configuration option 'Ole Automation Procedures' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.

When running

```sql
exec sp_configure
```

on the test server brings the record "Ole Automation Procedures" on the production server not.

### Update

I modify the code to catch the error:

```sql
Declare @Object as Int; 
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get','http://server/ws/service1.asmx/Test', 'false';
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send';
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT;
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Select @ResponseText Resultado;
Exec sp_OADestroy @Object;
```

The instruction "sp_OAGetErrorInfo EXEC @ Object" return: **(0x8004271A
) Error in srv_convert.**

According to Microsoft ([link](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3ben-us%3b325492)) is a problem of SqlServer. Since in my case the result of the webservice exceed 4000 characters.

**How I can call a webservice from TSQL?**

Comment: Did you run `sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;` on production as well?

Comment: Check the SQL Server versions on both your test and production servers.  It sounds like they are different.

Comment: @Andomar, `sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;` in the production server worked well.

Comment: What's the result of this query: `SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysobjects 
WHERE name LIKE '%sp_OA%' AND xtype = 'X'`

Comment: @Andomar, the result is: **sp_OACreate**, **sp_OADestroy**, **sp_OAGetErrorInfo**, **sp_OAGetProperty**, **sp_OAMethod**, **sp_OASetProperty**, **sp_OAStop**

Comment: That means it should be available.  I'd double check if you called `sp_configure, RECONFIGURE, sp_configure, RECONFIGURE` on the right server on the same connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it the following way:
Create a VBScript file (**callWS.vbs**) with the following code:

```vb
if WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 then
    Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
    http.open "GET", WScript.Arguments(0), FALSE
    http.send ""
    WScript.Echo http.responseText
else
    WScript.Echo "Not was provided the WS address."
end if
```

Then in TSQL:

```sql
declare @Command varchar(100)
declare @RetInfo varchar(8000)
select @Command = 'cscript c:\callWS.vbs "http://server/ws/service1.asmx/Test"'
print @Command
exec @RetInfo = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command
print @RetInfo
```

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon same error - "(0x8004271A ) Error in srv_convert."

To overcome char limitations, use #tmp table like below:

```
Create table #tmp(dt nvarchar(max))
insert into #tmp 
exec @hr =sp_OAGetProperty @objWinHttp, 'ResponseText'
Select dt from #tmp -- single column/single row.
Drop Table #tmp -- clean up
```

[Solution Source](http://jatindersingh.blogspot.com/2014/04/0x8004271a-odsole-extended-procedure.html)

Answer (score 1):

heey i have maybe some help for you if you want to call to call a HTTP web service from T-SQL (no SQLCLR) You can automate the XMLHTTP server object using the Object Automation extended stored procedures.

[Example](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/validate-a-url-from-sql-server.aspx)

I suggest you use the CLR or an SSIS package though.

Comment: Thanks but in this case would also have to enable **Ole Automation Procedure** which is where I have the problem.