# How to notify user by date saved in database

Tags: vb.net, notifications, sql-server-2000

I am using Visual Basic 2008 and Sql Server 2000. 
On all Forms I m saving a followup date user select a date and it saved in a relevant table, now at stored follow up date I need to pop up a bar or a notification inside application to tell user that this is you follow up date for this specific record.

Which are the ways I can do it.

any idea will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question completely. I don't know its for Windows form or Web form (Asp.net) Still I am trying to answer it

You can use  SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘MyTable’) after your insert command in your stored procedure  to get the last inserted id or to verify that it inserted data into table or not.

```
 public int InsertDate(string pid, string followUpDt)
        {
Try
{

            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@pid", pid);
            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@isScraped", isScraped);
            int identityId = (Int32)SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(CommonCS.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Sproc_FollowUpDate_Insert", param);
 if(identityId != null)
{
// it means Values has been inserted to the table
// Call a Java Script function to Show popup & message
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,GetType(),"showConfirmPopup","<script>disp_confirm()</script>",false)
}
else
{
//Operation not successful
}
}

        }

}
Catch(exception ex)
{
//Log Exception to DB  OR Send Error Email

}
```

> ///In Aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function showConfirmPopup() {
       var msg = "Successful "
   //Show Popup code here
     </script>
```

============================**UPDATED ANS**====================================
Alright You need to create a SQL Job make it occurring daily at specific time. SQL Job will call a Web service url(Invoke) through Stored Procedure

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259630/how-to-call-webservice-from-tsql-sql-server-2000)

Now you can check database dates against current date in that web service.

Comment: Its windows form software. Now what I have to do is I am already saving dates in db. Suppose I save a date to remind me on that date. now which routine can permanently look at that field in the db and keep checking when that date equals to current date it shows the msg of notification just like Facebook or any other sites. but the difference is first that routine have to confirm by checking that this is same date.

Comment: more simply it should be reminder which continuously keep checking the dates which are already save and have to trigger on time.