# Parse JSON from web in SQL Server 2017

Tags: json, sql-server

Is it possible to consume a JSON response from the web in SQL Server 2017 and then parse. I am interested in getting data from the public Open Sky API. 
I tried this but I just get NULL in @ResponseText :

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as nvarchar(max);


 Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
 Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
             'https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all', 
             'false'
 Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
 Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT


 Select @ResponseText

 Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I *do* have an SQL Server 2008 instance with OLE Automation enabled, so I can help with that but not so much with the JSON parsing.

First, pretty much everybody universally says, "Use SQLCLR to do this and not OLE Automation."  You should look at using SQLCLR for a new project.

Second, here's how I figured it out.  First, all the `sp_OA*` stored procedures return a result code.  We need to see that:

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as nvarchar(max);
Declare @hr int;

Exec @hr = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
select @hr;
Exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
             'https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all', 
             'false';
select @hr;
Exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send';
select @hr;
Exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT;
select @hr;
Exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @Object
select @hr
```

Running that returned `0`, `0`, `0`, `-2147211494`, `0`.  So the next to last call is the error.  The number translates to an HRESULT of `0x8004271A` (thank you `calc.exe`, although you can also use PowerShell: `'{0:x}' -f -2147211494`), but that didn't lead me anywhere. However, it does tell us where to use `sp_OAGetErrorInfo`:

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as nvarchar(max);
Declare @source nvarchar(255), @description nvarchar(255)

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
             'https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all', 
             'false';
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send';
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT;

Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object, @Source OUT, @Description OUT

Select @source, @description;

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Which returned the error `Error in srv_convert.`.  That error message led me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41368399/696808), which said you had to use a table and not a variable for the output if it was a very long string for some unspecified reason.

That gives me code that works:

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @Response table (txt nvarchar(max));

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
             'https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all', 
             'false';
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send';

Insert Into @Response (txt)
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText'

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object   

Select txt From @Response
```

---

SQL Server 2016+ comes with [JSON parsing functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server) which have a similar syntax to the older XML functions and are about as easy to use.  (Which is to say: not very easy until you're familiar with them.)

> - Use the **JSON_VALUE** function to extract a scalar value from a JSON string.
> - Use **JSON_QUERY** to extract an object or an array from a JSON string.
> - Use the **ISJSON** function to test whether a string contains valid JSON.
> - Use the **JSON_MODIFY** function to change a value in a JSON string.

There's also the **OPENJSON** rowset function.

Comment: OK, but how can I get the answer from https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all into a variable in SQL Server?

Comment: @stefan_77 Please see my updated answer with working code for the response.  Unfortunately, I don't have an SQL Server 2016 system available, so I can't help much with the JSON commands.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for your help! Now I will work with the parsing :)